# 414 error Getting an error on post and put response back to angular in javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, angular

I am doing a .net core 2.2 angular application that talks to .net core web.api it is a simple CRUD application that I am trying to learn angular with. I have tried multiple solutions but still getting error 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

I have tried taking out the base64 image thought maybe that was the issue but not still getting the same error.  I have tried adding in UseKestrel and ConfigureKestrel to increase the  options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize

```
 .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            //options.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = 300000000;
            //options.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = 300000000;

        });
```

I put this in both the webapi and the .net core angular app  in the program.cs file.  in my web.api I have also changed all gets to post and also disabled the limit.  put it on all methods in the web.api.

```
 [HttpPost("GetUser"), DisableRequestSizeLimit, RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue, ValueLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue)]
        [Route("GetUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(int? userId)
```

Stepping through it it looks like it calls the web.api then it will give me that error then my break point will happen on the web.api so when it gets back to the angular part where on the close of the dialog it never refreshes the grid. It is updating the database because if I refresh the page the updated record will show up.  I would expect it to refresh the grid but the error is happening so it angular's observable refresh never happens on the front end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your URI has a string stringdata that is too long. You can simply break it into a number of parts depending on the limits of your server. Then submit the first one, in my case to write a file. Then submit the next ones to append to previously added data

Comment: not sure how I would do that because it is happening when it tries to bind to the Angular material form. What is weird that it doesnt happen when it first loads it is able to load the table MatTableDataSource  I can click edit and it all loads right it saves correctly to the web.api it is only when I am trying  on the refresh I am calling my getData again it seems to error.

Comment: onEdit(row:User, index: number) {
        this.id = row.id;
        // index row is used just for debugging proposes and can be removed
        this.index = index;
        console.log(row);
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditUserDialogComponent, {
            data: { data:row}
        });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if (result === 1) {
                this.getUserList(this._domSanitizer);
              //  this.router.navigateByUrl('/userList-data');

            }
        });
     
    }